# Can't pull Fedora >34 for Docker?

Tags: fedora, docker

I'm using Fedora as the base image for a Docker. As I'm quite behind the current release I decided to switch to a higher version. Yet, it always fails as there's apparently an issue with the mirrors.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM fedora:34
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
RUN dnf update -y
RUN dnf install -y lightdm
#And so on
```

This works.

Using `FROM fedora:35` instead gives me:

```
docker build -t graphing:latest -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  514.6MB
Step 1/18 : FROM fedora:35
35: Pulling from library/fedora
054e3e802ba7: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:f1e3a29da8990568c1da6a460cf9658ee7e9b409aa39c2aded67f7ac1dfe7e8a
Status: Downloaded newer image for fedora:35
 ---> b97d90f26110
Step 2/18 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Running in dbdd43c68d78
Removing intermediate container dbdd43c68d78
 ---> 216a73ff85a3
Step 3/18 : RUN dnf update -y
 ---> Running in 19df4d4775c9
Fedora 35 - x86_64                              0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'fedora':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-35&arch=x86_64 [getaddrinfo() thread failed to start]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'fedora': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-35&arch=x86_64 [getaddrinfo() thread failed to start]
The command '/bin/sh -c dnf update -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Using `FROM fedora:36` gives me:

```
docker build -t graphing:latest -f Dockerfile .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  514.6MB
Step 1/18 : FROM fedora:36
36: Pulling from library/fedora
e1deda52ffad: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:cbf627299e327f564233aac6b97030f9023ca41d3453c497be2f5e8f7762d185
Status: Downloaded newer image for fedora:36
 ---> 98ffdbffd207
Step 2/18 : ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
 ---> Running in a670d11df939
Removing intermediate container a670d11df939
 ---> e0664f0626e7
Step 3/18 : RUN dnf update -y
 ---> Running in 9082965ff7ce
Fedora 36 - x86_64                              0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:00    
Errors during downloading metadata for repository 'fedora':
  - Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-36&arch=x86_64 [getaddrinfo() thread failed to start]
Error: Failed to download metadata for repo 'fedora': Cannot prepare internal mirrorlist: Curl error (6): Couldn't resolve host name for https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=fedora-36&arch=x86_64 [getaddrinfo() thread failed to start]
The command '/bin/sh -c dnf update -y' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

This error is not uncommon, but rather something that appears on a bare metal machine. I'm not having any custom configuration over the mirrors.
After searching a while I could rarely find anything like that for docker.

Probably using a fastmirror could solve that, but how to implement that in a Dockerfile?

Edit:

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.7, build 20.10.7-0ubuntu1~20.04.
$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9
$ runc --version
runc version 1.0.0~rc95-0ubuntu1~20.04.2
spec: 1.0.2-dev
go: go1.13.8
libseccomp: 2.5.1
```

Comment: Is your Docker version (or more precisely, runc version) up-to-date? This appears to be a solved problem.

Comment: @DanielB see the edits. I will run an ´apt upgrade´

Comment: @DanielB - solved it. Thank you

Comment: Great to hear you found a solution. Please do add it as an answer! You can accept your own answer 48 hours after adding it.

Comment: @DanielB - you can write it if you want to. I'll accept it. Free Karma :)